# How to check two timestamps in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a set of timestamps. I wish to compare them and find out which time comes before the other?  eg: 11:00, 12:30, 9:30, 6:30, 13:00. I have to compare each of these times to find out which came earlier? Using which datatype and function will i be able to do the same? Please, do let me know.

Comment: It's probably easiest to convert them all to `time_t` (e.g., using the `std::get_time` manipulator). Then you can sort and compare them as integers. Convert back to readable format with `std::put_time` when/if necessary.

Comment: it would be quicker to do a google search than to format a question like this here.

Comment: Can't answer this properly without some real code in the question.

Comment: Whenever you store the time/date date, usually the safest and simplest way is to use unix timestamp (32 or 64b), which is number of seconds since the start of epoch (1970). Works quite ok for most of the uses, except birthdays (for another ~200-300 years, then it will work probably well even for birth days of living droids). Then to figure out which timestamp happened sooner, you just compare them as numbers. Postpone all the formatting work as late as possible, formatting the value as string only to display it. Keep it as timestamp number for any internal usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort string containing time value only (no date), you may use a simple lexicographic sort. You need to make sure that all time values have the same number of characters. For that, you have to transform `9:30` in `09:30`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you define the two time stamps that you want to compare in a char array then you can use `strcmp( )` to compare which time comes after which. Like this :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    char time1[] = "14:28:51";
    char time2[] = "14:18:22";
    int result;

    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Time 1: "<<time1<<"\n";
    cout<<"Time 2: "<<time2<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n\n";

   result = strcmp( time1, time2 );

   if ( result > 0 ) cout<<"(Time 1)  "<<time1 <<" comes after (Time 2)  "<<time2<<" \n";
   else if (result < 0) cout<<"(Time 1)  "<<time1 <<" comes before (Time 2)  "<<time2<<" \n";

cout<<"\n\n"; 
cout<<"Press ANY key to close.\n\n";    
cin.ignore();cin.get();

return 0;
}
```